How can I write a regex that matches multiple lines that contain certain text but does not contain other text?
I am trying to write a regex to find text fields in my app that don't contain a maxLength validator. The text inputs can be written on a single line or multiple lines.
I'm not the best with regex but here are examples of what I need to match and what I have tried that is definitely not getting me what I want.
Things I need to match:
<AvField name="myName" />

<AvField name="myName"
  otherProp="" />

<AvField prop="" prop2=""
  prop3=""
/>

What I don't want to match:
<AvField maxLength={100} />

<AvField name="myName"
      otherProp="" maxLength={200} />

My Regex:
(?!.*maxLength)<AvField(.*\n)*?.*/>


Why are you using a regex for this? Seems so simple with basic string functions

Regex is not the best for this. If you have to, how about <AvField[^\/]*otherProp[^\/]*\/>? Also enable multiline.

@Evert I'm using the search in VS Code to find files that have these AvFields. Can you expand on what you mean by "basic string functions"?

@ChaseThorpe you could loop over the lines and use includes to see if a line includes a certain string.

Sorry I probably didn't explain my situation well. I am searching through hundreds of code files in a web application to find lines of code (that could span more than 1 line) that dont include a particular string of characters. I'm not sure I can just "loop over" anything here

Regular expressions are not very good at matching "X only inside Y", because there's not an easy way to express inside and outside.

If you can use lookarounds like in your current regex, try either <AvField(?![^>]*maxLength)[^>]*> or a tempered greedy token: <AvField(?:(?!maxLength)[^>])*> (probably less efficient)

Possibly something like this might work, or at least give you some more ideas:
<[^>]*maxLength[^>]*>|AvField([^>]*).?/>

It uses alternation. The part before the | is always tested, if it fails then the part after the | is used. In my regex there is no group set in the first part, only the second. This might mean if you write back captured group 1 followed by a newline then you will get some blank lines due to an empty group 1 on the maxLength lines.
I created and tested this in the Notepad++ environment, so possibly there might be some altering required to adjust to a VS environment.

I like the solution for programming, since you can access the capture group rather than the match, but I dont know if it can be applied in this usecase - if so I would be really interested to know how!
